# How do I return a list of tuples containing a phrase, and the number of times it appears in descending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

The following is the prompt for my homework:

"Write a function called phrase_freq that takes as input two file name strings.  The 
first file name refers to a file containing a book. The second file name contains 
phrases, one phrase to a line. The function uses a dictionary to map each 
phrase in the second file to an integer representing the number of times the phrase 
appears in the first file.  Phrases should be counted regardless of their capitalization
(e.g., if the phrase is "The Goops", then the phrases "The goops", "the Goops", and 
"the goops", should be counted).  The function returns a list of tuples containing the phrase and the number of times the phrase appears, sorted from largest number of appearances
to the smallest."

I think my thought process is along the right track, but I am not quite there.

The following is the current code that I have:

```
def phrase_freq(file1, file2):   
#1. Initialize a dictionary. 
    a_dict = {}
#2. Open the file containing the phrases from the book.
    in_file = open(file1)
#3. Iterate though the data in the phrases file. 
    for data in in_file:
#4. Add this data into the dictionary.
        a_dict = data
#5. Close this file. 
    in_file.close()
#6. Open the file containing text from book.
    in_file_2 = open(file2)
#7. Assign values to key and val variables in dict. 
    key = data
    val = 0
#8. Iterate through second file of book text. 
    for other_data in in_file_2: 
#9. Determine if phrases from file1 are in the book text. 
        if key in file2: 
#10. Add 1 to the instance which the phrase is found in text. 
            a_dict[key] = a_dict[key] + 1
#11. If not found more than once, keep freq. value at one. 
        else: 
             a_dict[key] = 1  
#Above giving me error. "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment."
#12. Close the book text file. 
    in_file_2.close()   
#13. Return the list of phrases and their frequency in text. 
    return list(a_dict.items())
```

The output should appear like the following test cases:

```
>>> phrase_freq("goops.txt","small_phrase.txt")
[('The Goops', 11)]
>>> phrase_freq("goops.txt","large_phrase.txt")
[('The Goops', 11), ('a Goop', 9), ('your mother', 5), ('you know', 3), ('your father', 3), ('never knew', 2), ('forget it', 1)]
```

Comment: post the sample data

Comment: I posted some examples in the edit!

Comment: 1. Initialize the counter dict using `file2`. 2. Scan the `file1` line by line and phrase by phrase to update the counter dict. 3. Before returning the list, sort the list inplace using `list.sort` with the frequency in descending order.

Comment: The code you provided may not work as you expect. For example, `a_dict = data` cause `a_dict` equals to the last line. You may actually want to use `a_dict[data] = 0`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to fix the SyntaxError that keeps appearing for me about a_dict[key] = 1? I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: That's because you did `a_dict = data`. Now `a_dict` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it's a type error.

Comment: Sorry, yes, a TypeError. Thank you all!

Comment: If you fix the first problem, the error should go away.

Comment: but your code has other problems. The keys of the dictionary should be the phrases in `file2`, not the lines in `file1`.

Comment: `key = data` makes no sense. `data` is the last line of `file1`, why would you use that as the key?

Comment: `if key in file2:` -- `file2` is a filename. So you're testing if the last line of the first file, is part of the name of the second file.

Comment: @Barmar I honestly really struggled with this problem. I am pretty inexperienced with coding. I thought that I could use the data from the original file to search for the phrases in the book text like the problem explained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214418/discussion-between-toeknee-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You should create the dictionary from the phrase file, not the book file. The book may not contain each phrase alone on a line.

You need to strip the line when reading from the phrase file, to remove the newlines.

You have to convert everything to a common case so that you can compare phrases with the book case-insensitively.

You have to test whether a phrase is in the line, not the other way around.

Finally, the requirements say that the list that's returned should be sorted by the number of times the phrase was found.

```
import operator

def phrase_freq(file1, file2):   
    a_dict = {}
    # initialize dictionary with all the phrases
    with open(file2) as phrases:
        for phrase in phrases:
            a_dict[phrase.strip().lower()] = 0
    with open(file1) as book:
        # check for each phrase on each line of the book
        for line in book:
            line = line.lower()
            for phrase in a_dict:
                if phrase in line:
                    a_dict[phrase] += 1
    # Return sorted list
    return sorted(a_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```